# Docker container bash terminal is irresponsive

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a MySQL instance running on a docker container. I am trying to access the bash terminal by running "docker exec -t myContainerID /bin/bash" for the container so that I can check into my MySQL and see if the setup is correct. Although after accessing the bash terminal, any command I run is irresponsive. Even something as simple as ls. Is there any way to resolve this or know what might be causing the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm no expert but have you tried `docker exec -it ...`? The `i` stands for `interactive`

Comment: My goodness, of course that's the problem! Thanks a lot mate, I feel very dull now haha

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the `-i` option, try running: `docker exec -ti CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash`

And just FYI:

```
--interactive , -i      Keep STDIN open even if not attached
--tty , -t              Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```